# Query on large collections using the MongoDb C++ driver differs from shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-c

Windows 7 64 SP1 --
MongoDB 2.2.0-rc2 -- 
Boost 1.42 --
MS VS 2010 Ultimate --
C++ driver

Following "Mongo in Action", in the shell:

```
for(i=0; i<200000; i++){
  db.numbers.save({num: i});
}
```

db.numbers.find() displays:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830a"),"num" : 0 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830b"),"num" : 1 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830c"),"num" : 2 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830d"),"num" : 3 }
...
```

So, replicating in C++:

```
// Insert 200,000 documents
for ( int i = 0; i < 200000 ; i++)
  c.insert(dc,BSON(GENOID << "num" << i));

//Display the first 20 documents
Query qu = BSONObj();
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query(dc,qu); 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
  cout << cursor->next().toString() << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504bab737ed339cef0e26829"), "num" : 199924 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504bab737ed339cef0e2682a"), "num" : 199925 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504bab737ed339cef0e2682b"), "num" : 199926 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504bab737ed339cef0e2682c"), "num" : 199927 }
....
```

Invoking db.numbers.find() in the shell has the same output. Why isn't it starting with {"num" : 0}?  It exists:

```
> db.numbers.find({"num" : 0})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("504bab417ed339cef0df5b35"), "num" : 0 }
```

The _id for {"num" : 0} is before the _id for {"num" : 199924}

And an index on "_id" exists:

```
> db.numbers.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "ns" : "learning.numbers",
            "name" : "_id_"
    }
]
```

If I add sort by _id by changing the query code to read:

```
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query(dc,qu.sort("_id"));
```

then it prints in order:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830a"),"num" : 0 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("4bfbf132dba1aa7c30ac830b"),"num" : 1 }
...
```

This doesn't happen with a smaller collection (say 200) of documents.

The question: Why does it appear that the C++ query isn't using the collection's index on _id? Or what else explains this apparent anomaly (or my lack of understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing and sorting are distinct concepts.  You can find data in an index without sorting the results; you can also sort results without using an index (though this isn't recommended).

Since you have not specified a sort order for your `find()`, the results will be returned in [natural order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order).  For a collection where you have only inserted documents (and never deleted or updated) the natural order should approximate insertion order (unless you happen to be using a [capped collection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections), which is maintained in insertion order).

Once you start deleting documents or updating them (which may cause them to be moved) there will be free space "gaps" created in MongoDB's [preallocated data files](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space#ExcessiveDiskSpace-DatafilePreallocation).  MongoDB will reuse the free space for new document insertions/moves .. so over time the natural order will no longer match the insertion order.

If you are expecting results in a specific sort order, you have to include this in your query.

Answer (score 0):

@stenni Thank you -- those "gaps" are the problem and led me to the solution.  The natural order in the shell appeared to be more "natural" than the C++ driver when querying, the latter starting with a very large "num". However, the fault lies in my methodology:

1. Insert 200000 documents in shell.
2. `db.numbers.find()`; first document listed was `{"num" : 0}`
3. `db.numbers.remove()`
4. Insert 200000 documents with C++ driver
5. `db.numbers.find()`; first document listed was `{"num" : SomeVeryLargeNumber}`

Instead, I should have used `db.numbers.drop()`, actually deleting the collection. Doing so means that step 5's first document listed is `{"num" : 0}`. `db.numbers.remove` obviously keeps the gaps.